# Html Frame Coding, Linking to info in another Frame

Tags: html, css, frames

OK so I'm coding something and i have a left frame, a right frame, and of coarse the main frameset html document. I want to have a link in the left frame that when clicked will jump to information on the right frame like  and , but i obviously not working, i believe I've seen it done, just don't know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to communicate between frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569768/how-to-communicate-between-frames)

Comment: you are still using `frameset` ? Consider using `iframe` instead. Have you set the `name` of each frame? Please post codes also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link **target** must be the **name of the frame** you want the content to load into.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="myRightFrame">Link</a>
```

Frameset:

```
<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
  <frame src="" />
  <frame src="" />
  <frame src="" name="myRightFrame" />
</frameset>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to open an external link, its a internal link, so intead of me scrolling down to the information i would click the link and it would shoot down for me, like the <a name=""> and <a href="#">, but in two different frames

Comment: Tried that, when i do it, it simply opens the left frame in the right frame for some reason?

Comment: <li style="list-style-type:none;"><a href="#Siberia Husky" target="RightFrame" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE">Siberia Husky</a></li>

Comment: Thats the code im using in the left frame, the #siberian Husky is the name of the link in the right frame, and the target is the name of the rightframe in the main frameset html doc

Comment: Do i still use the target then? Gonna try it now