# .NET IFRAME interacting with ASP Classic form

Tags: .net, iframe, asp-classic

I have this classic ASP form that needs functionality added to it. I don't know ASP classic. I do know .NET. I'm trying to think the best way for me to go ahead with this.

One of the options that were suggested was using an IFRAME, which would be built in .NET, nesting it in the classic ASP form.

Would it be possible for the two to interact with each other? Send values from classic to the .NET IFRAME and from the IFRAME to the parent form(provided the two pages are in the same domain) ?

Also, does anyone know if there are any compatibility issues with IFRAMES across browsers/mobile devices?

And finally, if anyone has any other suggestions how to approach this, I'm open to hear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569768/how-to-communicate-between-frames) might be of interest to you. Within the same domain, you can send messages between frames. I remember doing this at a previous employer once, but can't really remember the details. So this can only get you started, I can't provide a true solution.