# How to set SessionStorage of iframe with different domain

Tags: javascript, html, web, cross-domain

I want to set the SessionStorage of an iframe which is located on my page. However, the site in the iframe and my site have different domains. How can I handel that?
Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 2):

- If the iframe embed a content that have the same origin has your host website, they will share the same session storage.
- If the iframe don't have the same origin as your host website, **but** you have control over it, you can maybe implement something with the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API, to communicate with your iframe.
- If the iframe don't have the same origin as your host website, and you **don't** have control over it, you can't modify it's session storage for security reasons.

Take a look at this SO thread: [sessionStorage in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248128/sessionstorage-in-iframe) for more info.