# Why below code is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a frameset and 2 frames.

What I want to achieve is: A user clicks on an image/button. This opens a page in another frame. I can then call a function within that page.

Below is the sample code:

**Main_File.html**

```
<head>
     <frameset row="53px,*">
     <frame src="menuPage.html">
     <frame src="homePage.html" id="MainWindow">
     </frameset>
</head>
```

**menuPage.html**

```
<html>
<script>
  function ShowFunc()
  {
      top.MainWindow.location='homePage.html';
      top.MainWindow.Show()
  }
</script>
<body>
  <img src="abc.jpg" onclick="ShowFunc()">
</body>
```

**homePage.html**

```
<html>
<script>
   function Show()
   {
      document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display='block';
   }
</script>
<style>
   #hiddenDiv
   {
       height:100px;
       width:100px;
       position:absolute;
       top:10px;
       left:10px;
       display:none;
   }
</style>
<body>
   <div id="hiddenDiv">
     Some Text
   </div>
</body>
```

This is just a sample code.

What basically I want is, on load of `frame2/homePage.html` **hiddenDiv**  should not be visible.

But when I click on the image present in `frame1` then that div should become visible.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Looks like you want two frames to communicate with each other, check out this question: [How to communicate between frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569768/how-to-communicate-between-frames).

Comment: Thanks @SpencerWieczorek I found the solution from that page.

Comment: Great! I'll vote to close this as a duplicate then.